# why do I need -1 margin to stick button to corner in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, material-components-android

I have a coordinator layout with a bunch of stuff, and two buttons in the bottom corners. The buttons seem to be floating 1 pixel inside the corner, both horizontally and vertically. The only way to set them to the actual corner, is to actually set `layout_marginBottom` and `layout_marginStart`/`layout_marginEnd` on them to `-1`

No padding or margin is set anywhere.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            tools:menu="@menu/map_actions"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- not the one that causes problems, just included for completeness-->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/action_record"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        style="@style/Widget.Myapp.MaterialComponents.RecordButton"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_action_record_24dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible">
    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.BottomStartCorner"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:tint="?attr/colorOnSecondary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_people_24dp"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/actn_open_chat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_chat_24dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.BottomEndCorner"
        app:tint="?attr/colorOnSecondary" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the fab have default padding defined in its style.
You can check its source code here : [material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/res/values/styles.xml)

You can override the style of fab in the styles.xml

This will help you : [material.io](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#extended-fabs)